# why python list is not giving error when getting group of indices out of range

Tags: python, list

suppose we have python list

```
a=[1,2,3]
print(a[0]) will output 1
print(a[0:3]) will output [1,2,3]
print(a[4]) will output **IndexError: list index out of range**
```

But

```
print(a[0:4]) will output [1,2,3]
```

Why I am not getting error of **IndexError: list index out of range** this time?
Also same for

```
a[3:4] i will get empty [] but not the error
```

Comment: Slices are tolerant of being out of bounds. It's an API design choice

Comment: At least in part it's because slices can be open ended,  a[1:] includes an infinite number of 'out of range' indices!